# Putting the content of a token in quotation marks

Tags: c, string, token

In C:

1.- How could I define a token with the content of another token but in quotation marks?
Something like the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define _QUOTATION_MARKS "
#define _SOMETHING something
#define _SOMETHING_IN_QUOTATION_MARKS _QUOTATION_MARKS _SOMETHING _QUOTATION_MARKS

int main()
{
    printf( "%s\n", _SOMETHING_IN_QUOTATION_MARKS );
    return 0;
}
```

(2.- How could I define a token contenting just the quotation marks (") for the doing the what I asked in item 1.- ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will quote, [stringify](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html), `bare`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define QUOTE(x) #x   
int main()
{
    printf( "%s\n", QUOTE(bare) );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
int main()
{
    printf( "\"%s\"\n", _SOMETHING);
    return 0;
}
```